# 70-667 MS SharePoint Exam training materials

Tags: configuration, training, 70-667

Could someone please help me with the best training materials for 70-667,Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Configuring Exam?

I searched in internet but unfortunately couldnt get any downloadable materials.

Answer (score 1):

Some excellent material to prepare you for the 70-667 exam are listed below:

- http://www.benjaminathawes.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=17

This material is well structured at a high level, while also providing great detail in the articles linked.

- http://www.cbtnuggets.com/it-training-videos/series/microsoft-sharepoint-2010-config-70-667

The CBT Nugget videos, I would say are **worth every penny** with simple explanations in a wide variety of subjects. Another priceless aspect to this material is that each lesson contains wonderful demonstrations. As they say, a picture is worth a 1000 words. It’s wonderful to read and study, but when it comes down to it you must be familiar with the interface and these videos do just that!

These two items will refer you to some other great materials that I would recommend you reviewing, such as the "Professional SharePoint 2010 Administration" book.

Once you feel comfortable with the material above, I would also recommend taking a few practice exams at http://www.examcollection.com/70-667.html.

Hope this helps and Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Chatak for your suggestions.. will check it out :)

Comment: TrainSignal has some great videos as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find a great collection of 70-667 topics related to the TechNet sites:

http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Exam%2070667%20Study%20Guide/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Thanks Lex for your recommendations.. will check it out :)

Comment: You are welcome. That TechNet stuff is not for downloading, but you can print as pdf if you Need :)